# Return calculated cells ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, undo-redo

I put zeroes in a cell that had been entered manually. Is it possible to return these cells to their original value? I have not deleted or saved the file yet, crtl + z does not work

ArcGIS Pro V 2.8 Licencia online

Comment: Have you saved your edits?

Comment: No, I just Ctrl +z and no more